# Parse area code out of phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a list of phone numbers which are formatted in multiple ways such as: `(212)-555-1234` or `212-555-1234` or `2125551234`.

Using JavaScript, what would be the best way to extract only the area code out of these strings?

Comment: Need some more context about the data in which the phone numbers are found.  Is it one phone number per line? Are the phone numbers embedded in text?  Could there be multiple phone numbers on a single line?  Maybe you could include an example of the raw data from which you're trying to extract the area codes.

Comment: Answers below answered my question, I wish i could accept all the correct ones :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, remove everything that is not a digit to get the plain number. Then, get the first three digits via slicing:

```
return myString.replace(/\D/g,'').substr(0, 3);
```

Comment: This is best because if you need to do validation on the phone number at any point, this will maintain much more nicely than a regular expression.  It's also far more readable.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan it's using a regular expression. In fact, it's using a regular expression and two string methods. What on earth makes it more maintainable than a regular expression?

Comment: @canon - Any american phone number can be expressed a series of 10 digits.  All other formatting (whitespace, hyphens, parentheses, etc) is for human readability only.  While this uses a regex, it only uses it to pare the information down to the minimum amount needed.  This also makes the code more maintainable because it's (a) marginally easier to read, and (b) more extensible.

Answer (score 5):

Get the first 3 consecutive digits...

```
/[0-9]{3}/.exec("(212)-555-1234")[0]
```

Sample ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCpZW/)):

```
console.log(/[0-9]{3}/.exec("(212)-555-1234")[0]); // 212
console.log(/[0-9]{3}/.exec("212-555-1234")[0]); // 212
console.log(/[0-9]{3}/.exec("2125551234")[0]);​ // 212
```

Comment: Or save a few more characters with /\d{3}/.exec("(212)-555-1234")[0]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use my library.

https://github.com/Gilshallem/phoneparser

**Example**

```
parsePhone("12025550104");
result: { countryCode:1, areaCode:202, number:5550104, countryISOCode:"US" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex as `'^\(*(\d{3})'` should do it. Get the first group from the match.

Here `^` will start the match from beginning, `\d{3}` will match 3 digits. `\(*` will match the optional starting parenthesis. **You don't need to care about next digit or symbols after the area code.**

Comment: This isn't valid. Firstly it won't match any part of these strings due to having `\\d` instead of `\d`, and even when this is fixed it will also match on `555` and `123`

Comment: Please use regex literals, they're much easier to read than regex strings.

Comment: @DeanOC An additional escape char was used to escape the escape char itself. I removed that to avoid the confusion. Your second part is nor right. I am using `^` to match from the beginning. Syntax may have little issue but conceptually **it will match first 3 digits only**.

Comment: I'd use a question mark instead of an asterisk, but yeah, this'll do it.

Comment: My bad, I must have not copied the ^ when testing. However this regex is not correct when used against `(212)-555-1234` because it is including the opening bracket in the match.

Comment: @DeanOC I used `*` which means zero or more occurrence of `(`.

Comment: Yes, your regex will match on both `(212...` and `212...` but the OP doesn't want the bracket to be returned in the match, only the digits, i.e. he only wants to get back `212` in both cases. The first match will return `(212` not `212`

Comment: @DeanOC I put the brace outside the group definition. I think it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first 3 digits of a 10 digit number, or the first 3 digits after the 1 of an 11 digit number starting with 1.  This assumes your domain is U.S. phone numbers.